# Добавить блок после любого второго тега из семейства заголовков h1-h6 средствами js

Tags: javascript, html, cms, joomla

Есть код, с помощью которого происходит вставка  `<div class="block">Text</div>` перед вторым заголовком `h2`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
$('h2:eq(1)').before('<div class="block">Text</div>'); 
});
```

Подскажите, как сделать чтобы блок `<div class="block">Text</div>` размещался перед любым третьим html-заголовком. Фактически это или `h2` или `h3`.

Немного поясню зачем это нужно. Необходимо разместить блок в верхней части страницы. Перед первым `h2` уже установлен блок с помощью js что приведен выше.

Далее может идти как  `h2`, так и несколько `h3`. Таким образом если размещать `<div class="block">Text</div>` перед вторым `h2` он может существенно опуститься вниз страницы.

Поэтому возникла необходимость разместить блок после третьего тега из семейства html-заголовков.

Первый заголовок `h1`, второй `h2`, третьим по счету будет или `h2` или `h3`. Подскажите как доработать код выше, чтобы реализовать размещение блока по такому условию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function () {
  $("h2, h3").eq(2).before('<div class="block">Text</div>')
})
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас, работает!